# How can I encrypt a string with AES-128-CBC algorithm in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I have the following shell script which uses openssl to encrypt string:

```
API_KEY="qrBprgc/3dTjrrD@4t!9FcNjwT3_Ra"
DATE="Mon, 19 Mar 2018 12:45:05 EET"

aesivkey=$(echo -n "$DATE" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$API_KEY" -r)
aes128cbciv=${aesivkey:0:32}
aes128cbckey=${aesivkey:32:32}

private_key="test"
encrypted_private_key=`echo -e $private_key | openssl aes-128-cbc -base64 -nosalt -K $aes128cbckey -iv $aes128cbciv`
```

I am trying to make the same function in javascript(to use it in postman). At the moment I have the following code:

```
var dateString = "Mon, 19 Mar 2018 12:45:05 EET";
var api_key="qrBprgc/3dTjrrD@4t!9FcNjwT3_Ra"

//aesivkey=$(echo -n "$DATE" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$API_KEY" -r)
var aesivkey = (CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dateString, api_key)).toString();
//aes128cbciv=${aesivkey:0:32}
var aes128cbciv = aesivkey.substring(0, 32);
//aes128cbckey=${aesivkey:32:32}
var aes128cbckey = aesivkey.substring(aesivkey.length - 32);

var private_key="test"

//encrypted_private_key=`echo -e $private_key | openssl aes-128-cbc -base64 -nosalt -K $aes128cbckey -iv $aes128cbciv`
var encrypted_private_key = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(private_key, aes128cbckey,
{
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: aes128cbciv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Result in shell script: HSMD8RaXNbRrN4c1NzFXvQ==

Result in javascript: U2FsdGVkX1+uapLKV00iSOtj8eVpjfY4onoqQmoPPF4=

Comment: And, what happens? Error? Wrong result? Puppies? Do aesivkey, aes128cbciv, aes128cbckey resemble their counterpart?

Comment: @tevemadar I receive different results, shell script returns "HSMD8RaXNbRrN4c1NzFXvQ==" and javascript returns "U2FsdGVkX1+uapLKV00iSOtj8eVpjfY4onoqQmoPPF4="

Comment: Is the calculated key at least correct? Maybe the IV gets prefixed in the case of CryptoJS. Furthermore, you're using aesivkey intead of aescbckey in your call to encrypt.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Regarding "aesivkey" it was just a typo. Calculated key and iv are the same in shell/js.

Comment: You should really look into better ways of generating your keys and IV values. Note that you should not use above to create a secure transport mode, because you will **fail horrendously**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the result is `Salted__` (see the ASCII contents of the base 64 encoding, the first 8 bytes spell this word), i.e. it uses password encryption. This is probably because your key and IV need to be decoded from hexadecimals to a `WordArray` before use. If the key is a string instead of a `WordArray` it will be interpreted as being a password, and the key will be derived.

For instance:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(aes128cbckey)
```

and

```
iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(aes128cbciv)
```

---

Notes:

- Specifying the `keySize` in the configuration parameters is nice if you provide a password, but if you specify the key directly you should probably not use it.
- The developer that created CryptoJS should **really really really** not have overloaded the `encrypt` function.

Comment: I tried to decode my key and IV, then I still receive wrong result: "61KqddprvgB2Xq/YLO5Dmw=="

Comment: Hmm, possibly that `echo -e` adds a newline? The output seems otherwise OK wrt size. Try `-e -n`!

Comment: Oh, really the issue was in -e, now it works fine, thank you so mush for your assistance!