# AES CBC: JavaScript/CryptoJS Encrypt -> Golang Decrypt

Tags: javascript, go, encryption, aes, cryptojs

**Note: This is only for personal use and learning, I am not trying to roll my own encryption for public use.**

I need to AES256 encrypt a string, however my current attempts end up with a string like `Salted__Vέ��|��l��ʼ8XCQlY` server side when it is hex decoded. It should rather be a valid utf8 base64 string when hex-decoded, which can then be decoded to the original string. This is similar to the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363652/how-can-i-encrypt-a-string-with-aes-128-cbc-algorithm-in-javascript), however the salt was not the actual problem (despite the answer being accepted) and I have not been able to suppress the salt op by hex decoding the iv before use (as it suggested). Is there a way to do this?

I've tried several different methods and always end up in a similar spot. My latest attempt is such:

**encrypt.js**

```js
// CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding={pad:function(){},unpad:function(){}};

const SECRET = '394812730425442A472D2F423F452848';
const iv = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16));    

function enc(plainText) {
  var b64 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plainText, SECRET, { 
   iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    // padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding
  }).toString();

  // Don't need?
  //var e64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(b64);
  //var eHex = e64.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
  console.log("b64::", b64);

  return b64;
}

enc("SUPA_SECRET");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Now we take the `b64` result and paste it into the `JS_GEN` variable in the server side golang decrypt:

**decrypt.go**

([golang decrypt playground](https://goplay.space/#4EclNtIOpjU))

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    JS_GEN := "U2FsdGVkX1+CA3LZTXePlgoGqL8VkdgiDgUenZhH4kc="
    SECRET := "394812730425442A472D2F423F452848"
    //msg := "SUPER_SECRET"

    res, err := DecryptCBC(SECRET, JS_GEN)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("res::", res)
}

func DecryptCBC(secret string, target string) (string, error) {
    nilString := ""
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString(secret)
    //ciphertext, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(target)

    // Decode base64 string
    ciphertext, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(target)
    if err != nil {
        return nilString, err
    }

    // Create new cipher block
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nilString, err
    }

    // The IV needs to be unique, but not secure. Therefore it's common to
    // include it at the beginning of the ciphertext.
    if len(ciphertext) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    ciphertext = ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:]

    // CBC mode always works in whole blocks.
    if len(ciphertext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("ciphertext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)

    // CryptBlocks can work in-place if the two arguments are the same.
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, ciphertext)
    fmt.Println("ciphertext::", ciphertext)

    // Output: exampleplaintext
    return string(ciphertext), nil
}
```

The output will be something like:

```
ciphertext:: [136 227 244 124 124 92 162 254 1 147 235 213 8 136 129 150]
res:: ���||\�������
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I've removed hex encode/decode from the process.

Comment: You are not even passing the data inside `text` to `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString()` at the end of `decrypt()`

Comment: @Abdullah thanks, that was an oversight. I've cleaned up and updated all the code and the question to be directed at what I think is the problem now.

Comment: For AES256 use a 256 bit key. Your are using a 128 bit key in Go and (if I'm reading this right) a different 512 bit key in JS, which is non-sense. Also, hex encoding the cipher text after base64 encoding is redundant and wasteful. Choose one (base64 is preferable because the result is shorter).

Comment: @Peter I've removed the hex encoding, it's just something that was in every example I saw. Now as for the keys... how am I using different ones? They should both be using the same secret as the key (`394812730425442A472D2F423F452848`)

Comment: In the original question you *de*coded that string in Go but *en*coded it in JS. Now it seems you are using it as-is in JS. It's hard to help you if you keep changing the problem significantly.

Comment: @Peter apologies for changing it on you, that was when I refactored your suggestion to remove hex encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not totally sure why previous attempts have failed. It could have been one of many the different ways the encryption was implemented and/or configured on both server and client.

I've finally found what I was looking for. A simple implementation that just works out of the box. Here we will just use [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js#api) and [go-openssl](https://github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl).

**client.js**

```js
const msg = "SUPA_SECRET"
const key = "394812730425442A472D2F423F452848";
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key);

console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Luzifer/go-openssl"
)

func main() {
    encrypted := "ENCRYPTED_STRING_HERE"
    secret := "394812730425442A472D2F423F452848"

    o := openssl.New()

    dec, err := o.DecryptBytes(secret, []byte(encrypted), openssl.DigestMD5Sum)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("An error occurred: %s\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Decrypted text: %s\n", string(dec))
}



// OUTPUT:
// Decrypted text: SUPA_SECRET
```

Comment: Does this use 128-AES-cbc by default in JavaScript if we dont pass any parameter to this CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key);

Comment: I honestly don't know. Would need to dig into the docs/codebase

Comment: Any idea how? if we have to pass cbc mode for encryption and decryption

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using CBC mode in JavaScript (default), but CFB in golang. Try with `NewCBCDecrypter` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the decrypt code to use `NewCBCDecrypter`, this did not fix it. I've also updated the question to what I believe the problem is, that is the JS encryption is salting the hex string it produces, resulting in invalid b64 when decoded.